# Pascal's triangle in prolog with recursion and without cuts

Tags: prolog, pascals-triangle

I am trying to write a program in prolog that returns a list of Pascal's triangle. The list contains all elements of the row indicated by user input.
So for example:

```
ptriangle(3,X).
```

returns:
 `X = [1, 2, 1]`

So far I have:

```
sumC([X,Y],[Z]) :- Z is X + Y.
sumC([X,Y|L], Z):- H is X + Y,
                    sumC([Y|L],L2),
                    Z = [H|L2].

ptriangle(1,[1]) :- ! .
ptriangle(2,[1,1]) :- !.
ptriangle(N, L) :- Ant is N - 1,
                   ptriangle(Ant,L2),
                   sumC(L2,R),
                   append([1|R],[1],L), !.
```

But I am trying to find a way to do this without `!` and with recursion. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already using recursion in `ptriangle`. And you can avoid the cut `!`, at a cost of some non-determinism.

Take a look at this and see the changes:

```
sumC([X,Y],[Z, 1]) :- Z is X + Y.
sumC([X,Y|L], Z):- H is X + Y,
                   sumC([Y|L],L2),
                   Z = [H|L2].

ptriangle(1,[1]).
ptriangle(2,[1,1]).
ptriangle(N, [1|R]) :- N > 2,
                       Ant is N - 1,
                       ptriangle(Ant,L2),
                       sumC(L2,R).
```

That `append` at the end might become costly, so you can ask `sumC` itself to give one when it is building the list.

Try to work out how the changes affect the execution.

PS:

```
sumC([X,Y|L], [H|L2]):- H is X + Y,
                        sumC([Y|L],L2).
```

is an idomatic way of writing this:

```
sumC([X,Y|L], Z):- H is X + Y,
                   sumC([Y|L],L2),
                   Z = [H|L2].
```